# A domain entity exposing a repository-like method

Tags: domain-driven-design

Take this example. A **Supervisor** domain class exposes a method 
**GetUnderlings(DateTime from, DateTime to)** which will return all those people supervised by the given supervisor in the given period.

The method should go here for pleasing semantic reasons. But should go somewhere else for DDD purity. That's because I'm assuming to implement the method one would need to use a Repository, which it seems wrong to embed inside the Domain Entity. In that case, the method should go on a Respository or Service - **GetUnderlings(Supervisor supervisor, DateTime from, DateTime to)**

How do others handle this scenario?

EDIT: I think the forces can be described like this: according to OO principals, I want the public **interfaces** of my entities to expose a rich set of business-oriented functionality. BUT according to DDD implementation principals, the implementations of such methods might best be located elsewhere. In a service, for example.

How can this apparent conflict be resolved? The ways I can see are:

1. have the entity have a reference to the service, or service interface
2. Always make the client go to the service, not to the entity directly (result: loss of coherence, and totally not cool from an OO perspective)
3. use "Domain Events" (?)
4. use some AOP trick to delegate implementation of a method to the service.

Comment: I'd do `Service.GetUnderlings(...)` in this scenario, too. Let's wait for someone to write a more in-depth reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Supervisor` is an `Aggregate Root` it is valid to return `Underlings` list from `Supervisor` but just **READONLY** collection because `Underlings` shold be modified by `Supervisor` to apply domain rules and invariants to the modify action. (basic rule not only in DDD, is just well OOP design)

`Underlings` seems like a history `entity`. In most of the cases (I do not have enough context info to afirm this in your case) history `entities` are not `aggregate roots` and **ONLY** `aggregate roots` have repositories.

Keep in mind that if the retrieve of `Undelings` is for `UI` (not to apply an action with rules and invariants) you do not need to care about `aggregate roots`, `entities`, etc, because you should apply CQRS and use view services to retrieve plain data (1st normal form, not `aggregate roots`) to show it to the user. When an action is trigger by the user `UI` you need to check rules (that means apply DDD); you retrieve `Supervisor` from `Repository`, check `Underlings` ( remember, readonly collection) to take decissions, apply the action and save changes.

Comment: Thanks. Actually in my understanding your point is not quite correct. Items in an aggregate entity can only be accessed via the aggregate root (not via any other mechanism). This is not at all the same thing as saying that an entity should not give out references to other entities that are not in the same aggregate. Entities can be related, and yet not be in the same aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

**A common approach** is to expose all `Supervisor`'s `Underlings` as read-only collection. And if you need to implement a method that filters them by date range you simply add this method to class `Supervisor` as  `GetUnderlings(DateTime from, DateTime to)` and everything works.

**If common approach does not work** since your `Supervisor` has lots of `Underlings`, or it is time-consuming to retrieve all these `Underlings`, or ... there is a workaround - '[Separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html)' (PoEAA) pattern by Martin Fowler.

You can define an interface of component that returns `Underlings` within specific date range in your Domain Model, but implement it in another layer (e.g. Data Access layer).

In this case your domain entity has no reference to service and it does not exposes any 'Underlings'. All clients that need to get 'Underlings' call service and pass an instance of 'Supervisor' into method and date range.

[image]

Comment: But this still implies that the domain entity has a reference to a "service" interface. That's actually the crux of my question. Should the entity have a reference to such a service (even if just an interface)

Comment: I have edited my post and specified that it can be used only when 'common approach does not work'. First you should try to implement common approach that is easier and preferable, then look for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor should have a collection of Underlying if they belong to the Supervisor aggregate.

like

```
class Supervisor {
    private Collection<Underlying> underlyings;
}
```

Then the GetUnderlings(DateTime from, DateTime to) is filtering the undlyings. This is fine.

But if there are too many underlyings belonging to a Supervisor, this solution is not friendly to performance. In this case, I'd like to use make Underlying an aggregate root and use it's Repository to retrieve the result like:

```
interface UnderlyingRepository {
      Collection<Underlying> GetUnderlings(Guid supervisorId, DateTime from, DateTime to);
}
```

The client(maybe a MVC controller) invokes the repository directly. Then the problem is how to protect the invariants of addUnderlying which used to be protected by the Supervisor aggregate.
You could use either DomainService or DomainEvents.

The solution above is based on traditional DDD architectural model. Like @jlvaquero said, you could use CQRS instead.